# I am a beginner in web scraping Can anyone help me to find where in my problem?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am new just start learning python. I want get all links from page but when i use .get('href') its show error can anyone tell me where is my problem. and anouther question is how to use find_all multiple time like

```
page = soup.find_all('h2')
page

link = page.find('a')
link


import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://example/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
soup
link = soup.find_all('a')
link
link.get('href')
```

Comment: find_all actually returns a list of all, here in this case, 'a' tags, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: you need to iterate over `link` to get href from it if you still get the error please post URL if possible

Comment: import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://katmoviehd.sk/'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
soup

page = soup.find_all('h2')
page

link = page.find_all('a')
link

link.get('href')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. As your links in `h2` tag you can find all `h2` tag and which returns
>    list of elements where first element in list does not contain any `a`
>    tag so we can start from  index 1
> 2. And then find `a` get and extract `href` from it!
> 3. `i.find("a").get("href")` will work too!

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
re=requests.get("https://katmoviehd.sk/")
soup=BeautifulSoup(re.text,"html.parser")
page = soup.find_all('h2')[1:]

for i in page:
    print(i.find("a")['href'])
```

Output:

```
https://katmoviehd.sk/the-passing-2011/
https://katmoviehd.sk/vacation-friends-2021-hd/
https://katmoviehd.sk/d-p-2021/
https://katmoviehd.sk/sas-red-notice/
https://katmoviehd.sk/hes-all-that/
....
```

Comment: thanks it work i understand i need to use .find("a")['href']

Comment: you can use both it will work two, just different method which work same

Comment: Thanks boss got it and for tittle for i in page:
    print(i.find("a")['title']) awesome

Comment: sir can you help me more i complete full code and make a loop to get data from all page there have 550 page but i want to scrap only 10 or 20 page so how i condition it here is my code
while True: 
    next_page = soup.find('a', class_ = 'next page-numbers').get('href')
    next_page
    url = next_page
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

Comment: Please create separate question so it will be easy to understand and answerable to all SO Users!

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://example/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
links = soup.find_all('a')
for link in links:
    link_href = link.get('href')
# or
another_way_link_href = links[0].get('href')
```